# MikTeX does not find minionpro.sty

Tags: miktex, minionpro, miktex2.9

Recently, MikTeX came through a large update that introduces `MikTeX console`.  Since then I have troubles figuring out what to do in particular situations.

Recently I wanted to install `MinionPro` package, a task I successfully finished several times to date.  However, when trying to use it, I get error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `minionpro.sty' not found.
```

Funny thing is that the file is on the disk, in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\MinionPro` folder.

I first thought that some (FNDB) refreshing is needed, but I can't find that in the `MikTeX console`.  Next I tried to do that from the command console writing

```
texhash
initexmf -u
updmap
```

in both administrator and normal mode.  To no avail.

How to solve that problem?

Comment: You can refresh the file name database in the Console via "Tasks > Refresh file name database" in the menu

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I really did not see that.  Now it works, finally.  But why is command line update not working?

Comment: Not sure. Some command line tools need to be passed the `--admin` flags when run in Admin mode. But I expected the commands to complain if it is missing, not to fail silently...

Comment: I already tried that.  Without `--admin` I get no error;  with `--admin` flag I get error, can't recall which one now.

Comment: `initexmf --admin -u` should imho work. If not you should make a bug report (and first get the exact error message). `initexmf -u` will only update the fndb of the user trees.

Comment: Maybe you got an error with `--admin` because you didn't run the program with admin privileges? Anyhow, we can probably not find out exactly why things didn't work before.

Comment: @moewe I did run the program with admin privileges.  If finding the error and reporting it here would be useful, I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, the file should be in a `Local-TeXMF` root, not in the distribution root. If you do not have one, create it, and install in it all your local additions, respecting the `TeX Directory Structure`.

This being said, you can refresh the FNDB from MiKTeX console wopening the `Tasks` menu, which has sub menu for this job, to refresh `font map` files (after you've installed support for a  type 1 font) and to update  the `package database`:

[image]

Comment: I didn't put it in distribution root, MikTeX did it itself.

Comment: @Pygmalion: But, as far as I know,  it's *not* in the distribution (nor in TeX Live)! It has to be installed by hand. How comes you have it in MiKTeX TeXMF root?

Comment: No idea!  I did not install it manually.